# Form Filter on open

Tags: forms, filter

Can someone please help why I cannot filter for ABC , but if i enter (54) directly into the strFilter Line of code it works great

Dim ABC As Long
ABC = 54
Dim strFilter As String
strFilter = "[CompanyID] IN (ABC)"
Me.Filter = strFilter
your text``your text`Me.FilterOn = True

I expected the form to Filter the Field CompanyID for all values of 54

Again enterring 54 directly in (54) , it works perfect..